# Does there always exist a partition that can devide C_n^2 combinations into n-1 independent groups?

Tags: combinations

There are $n$ random oberservations. Suppose $n$ is even number. We are interested in the ratio of each two. So there are $C_n^2=n(n-1)/2$ kinds of ratios. To study the property of the ratios we need independent assumption. So we decide to partition the $C_n^2$ combinations into $n-1$ sets and consider each separately. From set standpoint, by independence I mean each combination in a group has no elements in common. Additionaly, the $n$ elements in a group fully cover $1:n$, as shown in the example below.

is it always possible to partition the $C_n^2=n(n-1)/2$ combinations into $n-1$ groups satisfying above requirements?
for example $n=6$, $C_6^2=15$

all combinations are

12 13 14 15 16 23 24 25 26 34 35 36 45 46 56

an independent partition containing $n-1=5$ groups is

- 12 34 56
- 13 25 46
- 14 26 35
- 15 24 36
- 16 23 45

I can prove that given a solution for $n$, $2n$ can be solved.

In addition, I can provide an algorithm for $n=2^k$

But what about any even number? anyone have ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the definition of "independent groups"?

Comment: sorry I did not make it clear. I re-edit it. I consider the independence of the ratio of combinations in a group, so the definition of independent groups should be "combinations in the group has no elements in common"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for are called "round robins" and exist for any even $n$. The idea is one has $n$ players (or baseball teams, etc.) and wants to set up a tournament of "rounds" where during the total set of rounds each player plays each other player exactly once, and during any one round each player is involved in a match against one of the other players. There are systematic ways to set these up for any even total number $n$ of players, some of which are discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament).

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I am looking for. It helps alot. But I don't have the reputation to vote up......

Comment: @user2792830 I believe you don't need a certain reputation to "accept" the answer, i.e. click on the check-mark to make it turn green (and doing so gives you some reputation points). However you may want to hold off on doing that since someone else may submit a more complete answer you find more informative.